# Does the restore force re-index the db for new custom dictionary index in the destination DB?

Tags: marklogic

Let's say source DB don't have custom dictionary index.

I added the customer dictionary index to the destination DB.

Now the question is after restoring do I need to force re-indexing the db for custom dictionary or it will automatically re-index the db?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will force a reindex, but if you change the custom dictionary you should reindex the data, as it will affect the stemming and tokenization:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/custom-dictionaries#id_42767

> You should reindex if you change a custom dictionary.